# How can i create nlp parser?

Tags: nlp

i need to create some nlp parser.
Can anyone advise me how to do it? Recommend any literature or web links?
Or Is there any library for my language( [CZECH REPUBLIC - Czech language](http://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8Cesko) )?
Sufficient to determine the subject and predicate.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a parser is not an easy task. You best option is probably to take an off-the-shelf statistical parser and train it on an annotated corpus of Czech text. You will probably have a better success with dependency parsers. I found a few useful looking sites: http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/czech-parsing and http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/pdt/Corpora/PDT_1.0/Doc/ws98/nlpch1.pdf

A good introductory text to NLP (which includes parsing) is Speech and Language Processing by Jurafsky and Martin. This is de facto THE Bible for NLP. You can also look at NLTK (natural language toolkit for python) http://www.nltk.org. It will have some parsers included so perhaps you can just train them on the Prague Dependency Treebank.